# Understanding matrix inversion via the adjugate

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let's say we have matrix ${\bf A}$. Its inverse matrix is given by

$$ {\bf A}^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det({\bf A})} \operatorname{adj}({\bf A}) $$

I know that dividing by the determinant makes sense because we are getting rid of the area done by the transformation but what is going on with the adjoint matrix?

Comment: I don't know of a good geometric explanation for this formula, in part because I don't think there is an easily accessible interpretation of the adjugate matrix, but you may find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254774/what-is-the-intuitive-meaning-of-the-adjugate-matrix) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12132/finding-the-inverse-of-a-matrix-using-determinants?rq=1) explanation enlightening.

Comment: @NoahSolomon thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we know that $AA^{-1}=I$. Also, $A[\operatorname{adj}(A)] = [\det(A)]I$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix)).

Therefore,

$$A \frac{\operatorname{adj}(A)}{\det(A)} = I \implies \frac{\operatorname{adj}(A)}{\det(A)} = A^{-1}$$

Comment: Right, the adjugate matrix of A is **defined** as a matrix of all "minors" of the matrix A, i.e., the determinants of submatrixes of A without one particular row and column. Because of the Laplace expansion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) the determinant of the whole A can be expanded in terms of these minors, which results in $A adj(A)$ being $det(A)$ times the identity matrix $I$.